# Jquery toggle between append and remove not working as i expected

Tags: jquery

The following toggle between append and remove does not work:

```
$('.t').click(function() {
            var className = $(this).data('class');
            $(this).toggleClass(className).toggleClass(className+'1');

            var newTable='<table style="font-size: 14;float:left;padding-left: 13px;" cellpadding="5"><tr><td style="color: #B2B2B9;">T1</td></tr><tr><td id="cap">20</td></tr><tr><td id="minseat">8</td></tr></table>';
            $("#newDiv").append(newTable).remove(newTable);
        });
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="t a" data-class="a"> 8cghfghfghfghfg</div>
 <div class="t b" data-class="b">20cghfghfghfghfg</div>
 <div class="t c" data-class="c"> 4cghfghfghfghfg</div>

 <div id="newDiv"></div>
```

[Working Demo Here..](http://jsfiddle.net/naresh_k28/m9ak9/5/)

Here, what i want to do is.. if i click on div.t, i want to remove the particular class(Ex: .a) and add respective class (Ex .a1), this one i achieved.

But i want to add a table while clicking first time, want to remove that added table while second time clicking.

how can i achieve this, please can anyone help me put...

Thanks

Comment: use `$(this).removeClass(className).addClass(className+'1')`

Comment: toggleing between classes is working, but i want toggeling between append and remove also..@DKM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To toggle append and remove, you can make use of the `data` property of the clicked element. Its a cleaner approach :

```
    $('.t').click(function () {
        //general stuff must happen everytime class is clicked
        //get the className from data- attr
        var className = $(this).data('class');
        //toggling to change color
        $(this).toggleClass(className).toggleClass(className + '1');

        //check if its clicked already using data- attribute
        if ($(this).data("clicked")) {
            //remove it if yes
            $("#newDiv").find("#tablefor-" + className).remove();
        } else {
            //new table - note that I've added an id to it indicate where it came from
            var newTable = '<table id="tablefor-' + className + '" style="font-size: 14;float:left;padding-left: 13px;" cellpadding="5"><tr><td style="color: #B2B2B9;">T1' + className + '</td></tr><tr><td id="cap">20</td></tr><tr><td id="minseat">8</td></tr></table>';

            //append table                
            $("#newDiv").append(newTable);
        }
        //reverse the data of clicked
        $(this).data("clicked", !$(this).data("clicked"));
    });
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/m9ak9/11/

Comment: please ask it as seperate question. there are many ppl who can help here :)

Comment: but if its big enough to ask a seperate question it MUST be a seperate question. By big enough i mean more that 10 lines of code

Comment: for every click we are changing the color and appending a table, and i want to send a ajax request, how can i

Comment: i want to send different ajax request for adding a table and different ajax request for removing table

Answer (score 0):

Just use an `if` switch to determine wether the table is already present or not. I modified your fiddle to demonstrate this: <kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/m9ak9/6/</kbd>

I added an `id` to the table to make it easiert to identify, but you could also look for it with something like this:

```
var findTableInDiv = $('#newDiv').find('table');
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but i want to add a table for every div means (div.t a, div.t b, div.t c) and remove as well..@imperative